# Why do a few resources suggest excluding the WordPress install from a Git repository?

Tags: wordpress, git, gitignore

While switching a WordPress site onto Git I looked for a .gitignore template. But I stumbled upon a reoccurring theme.

> Fact: you don't want WordPress core files, or your server-specific configuration files etc., in your project's repository. You just don't. – [Joe Bartlett](https://github.com/jdbartlett)

And the recommended GitHub .gitignore for WordPress excludes all wp-*.php files. [Wordpress.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Wordpress.gitignore).

Why is this recommended? Surely I’d want as many core files to be included as possible, otherwise I have to install WordPress on every server I deploy to.

*If context helps, I’m deploying it to a load balanced network with two application servers and two database servers.*

Comment: Yes, you'll have to install WordPress.  That's a *good* thing -- it means you're likely to have an up-to-date version, rather than relying on the 10-year-old version that your project got built with to even *be able* to update to the latest version.  And don't pretend it's a lot of trouble -- WP is famous for its "5 minute install".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I keep in a repository is the theme, never any core WordPress files. In the readmes I keep track of what versions it works with.

It's probably not recommended to help discourage modifying the core files.

Another idea is to keep WordPress as a clean git repo with your themes as submodules, that way you can upgrade/rollback WordPress separate from your themes. This is also how I maintain sites that use frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

This is recommended in order to keep only **YOUR** files into your repository. Then using a script (or something else) you can retrieve the WP sources.